# Trailing decimals in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column-formatting

[image: number column]

I have a number column in SharePoint Online list and I'm limiting it to have 4 decimal places in the end. However when I export the spreadsheet I can see more decimal places.

[image]

Is there a way to

1. Limit the decimal places to 4
2. Is there a way to show the numbers like so, "2.1450" will be displayed as "02.1450"

I'm fairly new to SharePoint Online lists and your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a test in SharePoint and entering data into a number column with 4 decimals, will round to these four digits, i.e. the entered number 2.12345 ends up as 2.1235, with normal rounding. Exporting that number still only shows the four decimals.

There is no Number format for leading zeros in SharePoint. To display  leading zeros, you can create a calculated column with this formula.

```
=TEXT(Number,"00.0000")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I know I can do that in excel but is there a way to do that in sharepoint online list itself.

Comment: I added details to my answer

Comment: Thank you @teylyn :)